# Why can't i use Type variable as a Type parameter to a generic class

Tags: dart

```dart
class Cage<T>{
  Cage();
}

class Chicken{
  Chicken();
}

main() {
  Type t= Chicken;
  var cage = new Cage<t>();        //Does not work
  var cage2 = new Cage<Chicken>(); //Works
}
```

Why cant I use Type variable as a Type parameter to a generic class?

here is a part of my problem, easy to solve by sending the type variable to the constructor but makes it ugly

```dart
class Injector{
  Map<Symbol, DependencyMapping> _dependencyMappings;

  //problem comes here
  RegisterDependency(Type type,[Symbol name=#unnamed]){
     //...
     var mapping = new DependencyMapping<type>(name);
  } 

}

class DependencyMapping<T>{
  //...
}

abstract class DependencyProvider<T> {
  //...
}

class ValueProvider<T> implements DependencyProvider {
  //...
}

class ClassProvider<T> implements DependencyProvider {
  //...
}

class SingletonProvider<T> implements DependencyProvider {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not possible in Dart as it stands today.

Parameterized types (things like `List<int>`) can take literal types (e.g., `List<Chicken>`) or `type` parameters (e.g., `List<T>` where `T` is declared as a `type` parameter in a generic, as it in Cage) as arguments. They cannot take arbitrary expressions, even if those are of `type Type`.

A variable such as `t` might hold a `Type` (as in your example) but in general it is really hard to be sure of that. It could just as easily hold a non-type value such as the number 3, because Dart's type system does not guarantee that something with static type Type really is a `Type`.

If we let these through, the system would be thoroughly corrupted. We could add runtime checks for that, but that would hit performance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not (yet) supported.

There was some explanation somewhere, I'll have to look it up....

Comment: ahah now i need to change 11 classes to be non generic and give the type to the constructor!

Comment: I thought to remember reading about this but wasn't yet able to find anything.

Comment: not a problem just wanted to make sure its impossible